# What is the current status of Multi-Sign function in bitcoin network?

Tags: multi-signature

Are they convenient enough for some real world transactions? Like an easy escrow that the two party can assign to a third party to finish a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

This topic has gotten a lot of traction recently, with new implementations continually popping out.

For example, there's a really nice standalone HTML5 app with slick interface called [Copay](https://copay.io/), developed by [Bitpay](https://bitpay.com/). There's also an online service [BitGo](https://www.bitgo.com/) (haven't tried this one though).

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It's a feature being used by a variety of wallets such as [GreenAddress](http://greenaddress.it/) and [BitGo](http://bitgo.com/).